# Creating Tuple<IEnumerable> for Local Files

Tags: c#, tuples, ienumerable

Apologies but C# is not my first language and I've inherited a program which I wish to change.

The code below works to list all files in a SFTP ready for download:

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<SftpFile>, string> GetRemoteFiles(string strHost, string strUserName, string strPWord, string strSFTPDirectory)
        {
            using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(strHost, strUserName, strPWord))
            {
                string result = "";
                try
                {
                    sftp.Connect();

                    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(strSFTPDirectory);                  

                    sftp.Disconnect();
                    return Tuple.Create(files,result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (sftp.IsConnected)
                    {
                        sftp.Disconnect();
                    }

                    IEnumerable<SftpFile> files = null;
                    result = "Error: " + e.ToString();
                    return Tuple.Create(files, result);
                }
            }
        }
```

But I am trying to recreate this to list all local files in a directory ready for upload and I cannot grasp how to do it.

I have tried the below:

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<Array>, string> GetLocalFiles(string strPDbOutboxFilePath)
        {
            {
                string result = "";
                try
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(strPDbOutboxFilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    
                    return Tuple.Create(files, result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> files = null;
                    result = "Error: " + e.ToString();
                    return Tuple.Create(files, result);
                }
            }
        }
```

And:

```
public Tuple<IEnumerable<FileInfo>, string> GetLocalFiles(string strPDbOutboxFilePath)
        {
            {
                string result = "";
                try
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(strPDbOutboxFilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                    
                    return Tuple.Create(files, result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> files = null;
                    result = "Error: " + e.ToString();
                    return Tuple.Create(files, result);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get the respective errors of:

`CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, string>' to 'System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Array>, string>'`

Or:

`CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, string>' to 'System.Tuple<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>, string>'`

Any help/advice is much appreciate.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FileInfo` is not a `string` and [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0) returns a `string[]`(filenames).

I would return a named tuple:

```
public static (IEnumerable<string> files, string error) GetLocalFiles(string strPDbOutboxFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(strPDbOutboxFilePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return (files, "");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return (Enumerable.Empty<string>(), "Error: " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you want to return a `FileInfo[]` you have to use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-7.0).

Comment: Given that the files are returned as `IEnumerable<string>` it might be better to use `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` to avoid making a copy of all the filenames.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Since the method name is `Get...` and not `Enumerate...` i would not return `Directory.EnumerateFiles` since the caller would  not expect deferred execution.

Comment: In that case, I would consider returning an `IReadOnlyList<string>`. That avoids potential "possible multiple enumeration" warnings - which would tend to cause the calling code to use `.ToList()` or similar to avoid the warning.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Maybe best would be to use `ICollection<string>`, then you can easily return a `HashSet<string>`(for unique files) without breaking code.

Comment: Yes that seems like the best approach - I just tried it, and it doesn't give you a "possible multiple enumeration" warning (I didn't think it would, but I tested it to be sure)